# How to return Promise using Rxjs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

I am learning RxJS/Redux-Observable in React.

But I have a question about `return Promise`.

**Without using RxJS/Redux-Observable**

**so that I can return promise to component let it can use `.then()` for next action**

In the Action of React

```
export const getData = () => (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const dataResponse = await dataAPI.getData();
        dispatch(getDataAction(dataResponse));
        return Promise.resolve(dataResponse);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
```

In the Component of React

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const {
        getData
    } = this.props;

    getData().then(function(response) {
        // I can use this response action for some UX Action.
    })
}
```

**With using RxJS/Redux-Observable**

**I don't know how to return promise**

In the Epic Action of React

```
export const getDataEpic = (action$, state$) => {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType(FETCH_DATA),
        mergeMap(action => {
            let _response = ajax.getJSON(dataAPI.getData());
            return _response.pipe(
                delay(3000),
                map(response => {
                    return fetchDataFulfilledAction(response);
                }),
                takeUntil(action$.pipe(
                    filter(
                        action => action.type === CANCEL_FETCH_DATA
                    )
                ))
            )
        })
    );
}
```

In the Component of React

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const {
        getData
    } = this.props;

    getData().then(function(response) {
        // How to get this response result ?
    })
}
```

I know using Reducer is the one of way to handle, but I still want to know how to return promise.

Thanks guys

Comment: You can use `toPromise()` to turn Observable into a Promise

Comment: @Martin Hi, I can't find toPromise() in the rxjs official doc usage? Would you mind provide more usage reference or codepen example? thanks a lot

Comment: I'm afraid there are no examples but it's a method on `Obseravable` class https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#toPromise

Answer (score 0):

So you made a classic mistake when we are returning a promise you should not return a new Promise for the success or error but return two function:

resolve -> for the sucess chaining it with then 
reject -> for the faileure chaining it with catch !

Hope this code will help you, tell me if you need clarification

```
export const getData = () => (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const dataResponse = await dataAPI.getData();
    dispatch(getDataAction(dataResponse))

    if(dataResponse.status === '200') {
      return resolve(dataResponse) }
    else {
     return reject(dataResponse.error)
  }   
})
```